Why can inconsistent function names be called correctly in the scenario of calling functions defined by c++in python code?
I saw a project on GitHub that involved Python code to call functions defined in C++.
Strangely, the function name defined in C++ is A, but it can be called through the name B in Python, where A and B have the same parts but slight differences.
For example, in C++, the function is defined as mt_load_float32, but it can be called through mt_load_float; or in C++, the function is mt_load_int64, but it can be called through mt_load.
The following are the specific function definitions (in C++files) and function calls (in Python files)(The files involved are all in the lib folder of the GitHub repository):
lib
-----cpp_extension
     -----mt_load.cpp
     -----wrapper.py
-----data.py
-----utils.py

In the mt_load.cpp file, we can see the definitions of these two functions in C++, as well as the implementation of Python calling C through pybind11++:
torch::Tensor load_float32(std::string file, int64_t size){
    // ……
}


torch::Tensor load_int64(std::string file, int64_t size){
    // ……
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(mt_load, m) {
    m.def("load_float32", &load_float32, "multi-threaded load (float32)");
    m.def("load_int64", &load_int64, "multi-threaded load (int64)");
}

The code in the wrapper.py file allows the functions defined in mt_load.cpp to be imported as modules like in Python：

dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

mt_load = load(name='mt_load', sources=[os.path.join(dir_path, 'mt_load.cpp')], extra_cflags=['-fopenmp', '-O2'], extra_ldflags=['-lgomp','-lrt'])

In the utils.py file, redefine the function in python(actually implemented in c++)
from lib.cpp_extension.wrapper import *

def load_float32(path, size):
    return mt_load.load_float32(path, size)

def load_int64(path, size):
    return mt_load.load_int64(path, size)

Finally, the two functions were called in data.py, but they used different function names.
from lib.utils import *
def get_rowptr_mt(self):
        indptr_size = self.conf['indptr_shape'][0]
        indptr = mt_load(self.indptr_path, indptr_size)
        return indptr


def get_labels_mt(self):
        labels_size = self.conf['labels_shape'][0]
        labels = mt_load_float(self.labels_path, labels_size)
        return labels


I am confident that there are no other function name definition conversions involved in the entire project code. But this code can indeed run on my machine
I hope that experienced experts can help me solve this confusion. Thank you very much

This looks like a bug to me.

But this code can indeed run on my machine

the functions you are pointing to are not used anywhere, so it is just untested dead code that won't run.

I see, how stupid I am . Thanks a lot!
